# Well ordering of $N^N$

Tags: well-orders

Is $N^N$ a well order under dictionary ordering?
I realize that the set $N/(0,0,0,0,0,....)$ does not contains a least element so it is not well ordered but why are we considering  $0$ when it is not in $N$.
Why can't $(1,1,1,1,.....)$ be least in $N^N$ when $0$ is not even in $N$.

Comment: Whether $0$ is in $\Bbb{N}$ or not is a matter of convention/faith/definition. You can choose yours. But, if $0\notin\Bbb{N}$, then what is the least element of $\Bbb{N}^{\Bbb{N}}\setminus\{(1,1,1,\ldots)\}$. In other words, if you have hang-ups about zero being natural, surely that is irrelevant for the purposes of this question.

Comment: quoting wikipedia "Some definitions, including the standard ISO 80000-2,[1] begin the natural numbers with 0, corresponding to the non-negative integers 0, 1, 2, 3, …, whereas others start with 1, corresponding to the positive integers 1, 2, 3, ….[2][3][4][5] Texts that exclude zero from the natural numbers sometimes refer to the natural numbers together with zero as the whole numbers, but in other writings, that term is used instead for the integers (including negative integers).[6]"

Answer (score 3):

Whether you consider 0 to be in $\mathbb{N}$ or not is irrelevant. You always get the same problem.

For example the sequence $(2,1, \cdots ),(1,2,1, \cdots ), (1,1,2,1, \cdots ), \cdots $ is strictly decreasing, which contradicts the well ordering and we did not even need to use 0.